# Remove extra padding top gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I'm an activity that holds a gridview with movie posters and some overlay text with the movie title.

I made an extra layout for tablets that also displays details about the selected movie in the same activity.

The problem is that when I use the tablet in landscape mode, for some reason the first row of elements expands vertically, occupying all the available space.

Here's a picture so you know what the problem is:

http://postimg.org/image/rgwakvlq3/

This is my layout file for tablets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.madelenko.movierating.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:context="com.example.madelenko.movierating.MainActivity">

                <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/gridview"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:numColumns="@integer/column_count"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grid_vert_spacing"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_container"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is the relative layout that contains the elements in each movie poster:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/grid_element_parent">

    <!-- View to be populated with a movie poster-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!--View to be populated with the movie's title and rating-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="@integer/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/text_overlay_height"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/overlay_text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The correct UI should look like this:

http://postimg.org/image/939s90085/

(But with 3 cols instead of 2)

How can I fix this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your `ImageView`:

```
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```